# Make function sync or async depending on argument values

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.12

Since 3.12, would it be possible to make a method that can be either async or not and used like

```py
async def maybe_async(something_that_makes_it_async=None):
    ...

res = await maybe_async(some_http_interface)
```

and

```py
res = maybe_async()
```

are both valid.

As far as I know, you can do it by just wrapping the function with `asyncio.run()`,  but this would be cleaner for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

"*As far as I know, you can do it by just wrapping the function with asyncio.run(), but this would be cleaner for the caller.*"

No you can't do that. From Asyncio's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run):

> This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is
> running in the same thread.
>
> ...
>
> If loop_factory is not None, it is used to create a new event loop; >otherwise asyncio.new_event_loop() is used.

`asyncio.run()` will create a new event loop for you.

One solution would be to write an async function which `await`s or
directly returns the result of calling the passed function. It's not exactly what you asked for, but it gives you the ability to run a normal function or an async function by `await`ing on it.

Here I wrote a very simple version of it:

```py
import asyncio
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction

async def maybe_sync(fn):
    if iscoroutinefunction(fn):
        return await fn()

    # Here you can run it in an executor if it takes a long time to run.
    return fn()

def normal_function():
    return 10

async def async_function():
    return 10

async def main():
    res1 = await maybe_sync(normal_function)
    res2 = await maybe_sync(async_function)
    print(res1, res2)

asyncio.run(main())
```

It may not suit your application as it blocks the main thread to run the `fn` if it's a blocking call. You could run it in an thread/process executor for instance.